# Java HashMap.get() returns null when I create a new instance of an object as a key

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm making a spreadsheet application and I'm using a HashMap to store the data in the cells. As the key I'm using a Point class, which only has the number of rows and colums. The problem I'm having is that if I use the HashMap.get() with a new Point, it returns a null value.

```
    HashMap<Point, String> cache = new HashMap<Point, String>();
    Point p1 = new Point(1,1);
    Point p2 = new Point(2,2);
    cache.put(p1, "Test: 1,1");
    cache.put(p2, "Test: 2,2");

    int maxRow = 2;
    int maxCol = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= maxCol; j++) {
            System.out.print(cache.get(new Point(i,j)));
            if (j < maxCol) 
                System.out.print("\t");
            if (j == maxRow)
                System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

This returns:

```
null     null
null     null
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't find it myself. Also, if you happen to know if there is a better data structure for storing data from cells I'd love to hear it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hashcode/equals implemented for `Point` class? Indeed, by default, two instances are considered as distinct, since hashcode is based on object's memory address.

Comment: Aha, thanks! At least it doesn't return nulls, but now it returns the same value twice on each row, instead of a value and a null. Do you have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @ThaRemo Have you tested your new equals method? You need to check both that it returns true for objects you consider equal, and that it returns false for objects you consider different.

Comment: @ThaRemo Your code (including my hashcode/equals) well outputs: `Test: 1,1 null                                    
null Test: 2,2`  What is wrong?!

Comment: Never mind, I made a little mistake in the Point constructor. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detail my comment above, your Point class should implement hashcode and equals like following:
(many implementations exist, it's just one that works)
Supposing that your instance's variables are `x` and `y`.

```
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Point point = (Point) o;

        if (x != point.x) return false;
        if (y != point.y) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result + y;
        return result;
    }
```

Otherwise, if you don't override those methods, `Object`'s Javadoc explains well your issue:

```
As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
     * class {@code Object} does return distinct integers for distinct
     * objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal
     * address of the object into an integer, but this implementation
     * technique is not required by the
     * Java<font size="-2"><sup>TM</sup></font> programming language.)
     *
     * @return  a hash code value for this object.
     * @see     java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     * @see     java.lang.System#identityHashCode
     */
    public native int hashCode();
```

Thus, `new Point(1,2)` would not be considered as equal to `new Point(1,2)` and therefore, could never be retrieved from your `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `Point`'s equals method uses `==` i.e. object identity. Because Hashmap uses the equals method, it ends up comparing the key using `==` which would return false unless it's the same object.

To fix this, Implement Point's `equals` and `hashCode` method so that `point1.equals(point2)` returns true if the coordinates are same.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are using the Point as the key to the hashmap you would need to override the default equals and hashCode method

## Untested Code

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){

if (obj == null) 
    return false;
if (obj == this) 
    return true;
if (!(obj instanceof Point.class))
    return false;
Point point = (Point) obj;
return this.x == point.x && this.y == point.y;
}
```

Comment: Drop those "stupid";) returns at the end: replace by just:  `return this.x == point.x && this.y == point.y`