# Hashtable returns null or throws exception when the key is not exist?

Tags: java, dictionary

[Java HashMap.get() returns null when I create a new instance of an object as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307443/java-hashmap-get-returns-null-when-i-create-a-new-instance-of-an-object-as-a-k)

For the above link, it seems that the `HashMap` returns null when the key is not existed in the map. However when I try:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> hs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
int value = hs.get(1);
System.out.println(value);
```

It throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What's the issue? How to let the `Map` returns a null other than throws an exception in such situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int` is a primitive and doesn't support `null` value. The code you have there can be understood like this:

```
Integer temp = hs.get(1);
int value = temp.intValue();
            ^null^
```

Since this `Integer temp` variable is `null`, when performing the auto unboxing to `int` you have a `NullPointerException`.

To avoid this *problem*, use `Integer` variable, not `int`:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> hs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
Integer value = hs.get(1);
System.out.println(value);
```